# Properties in UserControl are null when being set

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a user control which contains a number of labels, which I want to set with values from a controller class.

In my user control I have set the labels a public properties like thus:

```
Public Label MyLabel
{
    get{ return this.Label1;}
    set {this.Label1 = value;}
}
```

Also I have created an interface for this user control listing the properties.

In my controller, which is where I want to set everything up, I have created a private variable

```
private IUserControlObj MyControlUser
```

In the constructor of the Controller I set up the object thus:

```
this.MyControlUser = new UserControlObj();
```

I can see my the properties in the method where I want to set everything up, but when I go to run the code, I am getting Object not set to an instance of an object against my properties.

Where am I failing to get this right? I want to set my data and objects in my controller, not on page.

Comment: Can you provide the code where the exception is coming up?

Comment: It is when I am setting the property thus: MyControlUser.MyLabel.Text = "Hello World";

Comment: Is the UserControlObj constructor calling the initializeComponent() function?

Comment: No, what and where is this meant to go?

Comment: Go to your user control class and check what is written in the constructor method. The constructor should be calling the initializeComponent() method which initializes the user control components.

Comment: This is asp.net. InitializeComponent() does not exist

Comment: Sorry I thought it was C# winform. I have no experience with asp.net . best luck

Answer (score 0):

solved by passing the page as a parameter in the constructor of the class being used.

Comment: Now declare your answer an "answer" so that everyone sees it has been answered and doesn't waste their time. Please. :) Alternatively, if you think this isn't of interest to others (question archive), delete the question entirely.